# Finding the initial sampled time window after using SAMPLE BY again

Tags: sql, questdb

I can't seem to find a perhaps easy solution to what I'm trying to accomplish here, using SQL and, more importantly, QuestDB. I also find it hard to put my exact question into words so bear with me.

**Input**

My real input is different of course but a similar dataset or case is the `gas_prices` table on the demo page of QuestDB. On https://demo.questdb.io, you can directly write and run queries against some sample database, so it should be easy enough to follow.

The main task I want to accomplish is **to find out *which month* was responsible for the year's highest galon price**.

**Output**

Using the following query, I can get the average galon price per month just fine.

```
SELECT timestamp, avg(galon_price) as avg_per_month FROM 'gas_prices' SAMPLE BY 1M
```

| timestamp | avg_per_month |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.6724 |
| 2000-07-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.69275 |
| 2000-08-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.635 |
| ... | ... |

Then, I get all these monthly averages, group them by year and return the maximum galon price *per year* by wrapping the above query in a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT timestamp, max(avg_per_month) as max_per_year FROM (
  SELECT timestamp, avg(galon_price) as avg_per_month FROM 'gas_prices' SAMPLE BY 1M
) SAMPLE BY 12M
```

| timestamp | max_per_year |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.69275 |
| 2001-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.767399999999 |
| 2002-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.52075 |
| ... | ... |

**Wanted output**

I want to know which month was responsible for the maximum price of a year.

Looking at the output of the above query, we see that the maximum galon price for the year 2000 was 1.69275. Which month of the year 2000 had this amount as average price? I'd like to display this month in an additional column.

For the first row, July 2000 is shown in the additional column for year 2000 because it is responsible for the highest average price in 2000. For the second row, it was May 2001 as that month had the highest average price of 2001.

| timestamp | max_per_year | which_month_is_responsible |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.69275 | 2000-07-05T00:00:00.000000Z |
| 2001-01-05T00:00:00.000000Z | 1.767399999999 | 2001-05-05T00:00:00.000000Z |
| ... | ... |  |

**What did I try?**

I tried by adding a subquery to the `SELECT` to have a "duplicate" of some sort for the `timestamp` column but that's apparently never valid in QuestDB (?), so probably the solution is by adding even more subqueries in the `FROM`? Or a UNION?

Who can help me out with this? The data *is* there in the database and it *can* be calculated. It's just a matter of getting it out.

Comment: Can you update your post with your sample input tables? Even craft it if you don't have one, but making sure you can reach the exact expected output from the input.

Comment: @lemon I've updated my question and replaced the sample dataset entirely to easily check it online on the demo page of QuestDB. I believe this is what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'wanted output' can be achieved with window functions.
Please have a look at:

```
CREATE TABLE electricity (ts TIMESTAMP, consumption DOUBLE) TIMESTAMP(ts);

INSERT INTO electricity 
SELECT (x*1000000)::timestamp, rnd_double() 
FROM long_sequence(10000000);

SELECT day, ts, max_per_day 
FROM 
(
  SELECT timestamp_floor('d', ts) as day, 
         ts, 
         avg_in_15_min as max_per_day, 
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp_floor('d', ts) ORDER BY avg_in_15_min desc) as rn_per_day 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ts, avg(consumption) as avg_in_15_min 
    FROM electricity 
    SAMPLE BY 15m
  ) 
) WHERE rn_per_day = 1
```

Comment: Awesome! It's unfortunate I just edited my question to be less specific to my use case and to make it more "accessible" by providing a sample db as asked in the comments, but your solution seems to be what I want.

It would've never occurred to me that I should use something like `row_number() OVER`.

To be complete, I took your query and changed it to match the dataset in my edited question.

Comment: ```SELECT year, max_per_year, timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT timestamp_floor('y', timestamp) as year,
        timestamp,
        avg_per_month as max_per_year,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp_floor('y', timestamp) ORDER BY avg_per_month desc) as rn_per_month
  FROM (
    SELECT timestamp, avg(galon_price) as avg_per_month FROM 'gas_prices' SAMPLE BY 1M
  )
)
WHERE rn_per_month = 1;```